# FPDF Class and WordPress PDF upload

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, fpdf

I'm uisng FPDF for my PDF handling in my webshop. Whenever a user checks out I want to generate a PDF with all the data from the shopping cart and afterwards upload the PDF to the media library in WordPress.

I've tried a bunch of stuff now, but I haven't made anything yet that works. So far I can only save the PDF to a different folder  by writing:

```
$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/invoice/nameofinvoice.pdf', 'F');
```

My code looks like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $pdf->Output('dimserPdf2014.pdf', 'F');
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

// die(var_dump($movefile));

$wp_filetype = $movefile['type'];
$filename = $movefile['file'];
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype,
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

// Id of attachment if needed
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename);
```

It does upload a file to the media library, but the file is empty, and if I uncomment the die > var_dump function I also get an array with simply nothing saying it's an empty file.

This is the script/class I'm using: 
http://www.fpdf.org/
and the Output method accepts two parameters, filename and method of saving/downloading. As you can see here: 
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm and I've tried every single parameter so far with no luck.

Any idea on why WordPress uploads an empty file and not my PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been doing some work with [mPDF](http://mpdf1.com/), which is a (better documented & maintained imho) fork of FPDF. From what I can see in the documentation, the [Output](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125) method doesn't return anything unless you pass the "S" *dest*.

Also, according to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) the *file* in `wp_handle_upload` is for working on one item in the `$_FILES` superglobal. You shouldn't need it in your case if you generate your PDF in the uploads directory.

Try this instead:

```
if ( ! function_exists ... ;
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$uploadedfile = trailingslashit ( $wp_upload_dir['path'] ) . 'dimserPdf2014.pdf';
$pdf->Output($uploadedfile, 'F');

$attachment = array(
   'guid' => trailingslashit ($wp_upload_dir['url']) . basename( $uploadedfile ),
   'post_mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
   'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
   'post_content' => '',
   'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

// Id of attachment if needed
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadedfile);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working just great and I will definitely look into mPDF which seems to be capable of a lot more than fPDF :)